# Divi Theme and woocommerce_product_query not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

I am calling `woocommerce_product_query` but is not working in `Divi theme`.
I checked and it works with other built-in wordpress themes.

I am using `Query Monitor` and I can see that its fired correctly but still I get all products and not the one I hardcoded in `post__in`.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_pre_get_posts_query', 9999 );
function my_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {
    
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    
    $query->set( 'post__in', ['245374','245372'] );
}
```

Is there any known interference with Divi? What can possible go wrong? I checked both with parent and child Divi theme.

Divi Theme code:

```
/**
     * Filter the products query arguments.
     *
     * @since 4.0.5
     *
     * @param array $query_args Query array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function filter_products_query( $query_args ) {
        if ( is_search() ) {
            $query_args['s'] = get_search_query();
        }

        if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) ) {
            $query_args['meta_query'] = WC()->query->get_meta_query( et_()->array_get( $query_args, 'meta_query', array() ), true );
            $query_args['tax_query']  = WC()->query->get_tax_query( et_()->array_get( $query_args, 'tax_query', array() ), true );

            // Add fake cache-busting argument as the filtering is actually done in self::apply_woo_widget_filters().
            $query_args['nocache'] = microtime( true );
        }

        return $query_args;
    }
```

Or this part in the get_shop public function of the theme:

```
global $wp_the_query;

        $query_backup = $wp_the_query;

        $is_offset_valid = absint( $offset_number ) > 0;
        if ( $is_offset_valid ) {
            self::$offset = $offset_number;

            add_filter(
                'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query',
                // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Arrays.CommaAfterArrayItem.NoComma -- This is a function call.
                array( 'ET_Builder_Module_Shop', 'append_offset' )
            );

            add_filter(
                'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query_results',
                array( 'ET_Builder_Module_Shop', 'adjust_offset_pagination' )
            );
        }

        if ( 'product_category' === $type || $use_current_loop ) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', array( $this, 'filter_products_query' ) );
            add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'apply_woo_widget_filters' ), 10 );
        }

        if ( $use_current_loop ) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', array( $this, 'filter_vendors_products_query' ) );
        }

        $shop = do_shortcode( $shortcode );

        if ( $is_offset_valid ) {
            remove_filter(
                'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query',
                array( 'ET_Builder_Module_Shop', 'append_offset' )
            );

            remove_filter(
                'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query_results',
                array( 'ET_Builder_Module_Shop', 'adjust_offset_pagination' )
            );

            self::$offset = 0;
        }

        remove_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', array( $this, 'set_default_orderby' ) );

        if ( $use_current_loop ) {
            remove_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', array( $this, 'filter_vendors_products_query' ) );
        }

        if ( 'product_category' === $type || $use_current_loop ) {
            remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'apply_woo_widget_filters' ), 10 );
            remove_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', array( $this, 'filter_products_query' ) );
        }

        $wp_the_query = $query_backup;
```

Comment: I have just tested in Divi theme and working fine for me. Which version you are using.

Comment: @Bhautik did you try woocommerce_product_query and it works?

Comment: Yes I have used `woocommerce_product_query`

Answer (score 0):

I dont have Divi to test it but i know that theme have own settings for queries.

Try this solution that i found

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_pre_get_posts_query' );
function my_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
    if ( $q->is_main_query() && ( $q->get( 'wc_query' ) === 'product_query' ) ) {
         $query->set( 'post__in', ['245374','245372'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: tested it but didnt work...

Comment: Then i suggest to ask theme devs for the best solution. Like i said i dont have the theme to look into it. Maybe search in theme for woocommerce_product_query and see if they modify it.

Comment: I asked and they override woocommerce theme. its not that easy to change it thats why I asked here if anyone has done anything similar

Comment: Then maybe share how they change it?

Comment: I updated my post with the code I found which I think it has to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it may help you.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_pre_get_posts_query' );
function my_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {
    
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array( array(
       'post__in' => ['245374','245372']     
    )));

}
```